# Некликабельные кнопки чата

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, чат

Установил [вот этот чат](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wise-chat/) довольно красивый и простой и функционал приемлемый.
Однако, все кнопки в нем оказались некликабельными, текст в чат не отравляется.
На странице блога ошибок относящихся к чату не нашел.
Такая проблема была у кого то. Но решения ее не помню.
Что-то из скриптовых файлов удалялась строчка какая то.
Но тогда еще и сам плагин не обновлялся.
Код изменился в нем немного.
А проблема осталась.

Comment: вот пример на сайте http://mytest.allwebs.ru/чат/

Comment: У вас там ошибки в консоли. пока не исправите - ничего работать не будет. Код падает на них.

Comment: А в консоли то что не так может быть ? Это чистая копия с сайта вордпресс без прочих плагинов. Если только переустановить копию эту может ошибка пропадёт. А где именно увидели ошибку какую ?

Comment: http://take.ms/RWZJS

Comment: http://take.ms/BtMck

Comment: А вот судя по второй ссылке это больше видно ссылается именно на сам чат файл и именно эту строчку кажись и надо в нем поменять удалить эту amp

Comment: @KAGGDesign я нашел тот код который был указан во 2ой ссылке. он немного иначе выглядит на 2 знака в 8 строчке https://pastebin.com/MV0XZ2kT ну удалив 0 && в этой строке, заработали кнопки